# How to destroy the optionmenu in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I click the "Hamstring" button, the option menu should be displayed and the button should be disabled. When I click "refresh" button, the option menu should disappear and the "Hamstring" button should go back to its normal state.

I need it to work this way because I will have few other buttons with different optionmenus later

I'm probably not coding my functions correctly. Tried everything I know and could find. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import yoga_Images
import yogaposes

root = tk.Tk()

yoga_dict2 = {}
for yoga_name2 in yogaposes.hamstringposes:
    yoga_dict2[yoga_name2] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./yoga_Images/{}.png".format(yoga_name2)))

variable2 = tk.StringVar(root)
variable2.set(yogaposes.hamstringposes[0])

def change_image2(b):
    print(b)  # selected option
    my_image.config(image=yoga_dict2[b])

def onclickHamstring(args):
    if args == 1:
        opt2 = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable2, *yogaposes.hamstringposes, command=change_image2)
        opt2.config(width=50, font=('Helvetica', 12))
        opt2.pack(pady=10)
        if (ci2_k['state'] == tk.NORMAL):
            ci2_k['state'] = tk.DISABLED
        else:
            ci2_k['state'] = tk.NORMAL
        
ci2_k = tk.Button(root, text="Hamstring poses", command=lambda:onclickHamstring(1))
ci2_k .pack(side="left",pady=10)

def normalizebuttons():
    ci2_k['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    opt2.destroy()
    
normalizeyogabuttons = tk.Button(root, text="Refresh", command=normalizebuttons)
normalizeyogabuttons.pack(side="left",pady=10)

my_image = tk.Label(root)
my_image.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/ad/Documents/Python/Project_tkinter/test1.py", line 270, in normalizebuttons
    opt2.destroy()
NameError: name 'opt2' is not defined
```

Version 2:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import yoga_Images
import yogaposes

root = tk.Tk()

yoga_dict2 = {}
for yoga_name2 in yogaposes.hamstringposes:
    yoga_dict2[yoga_name2] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./yoga_Images/{}.png".format(yoga_name2)))

variable2 = tk.StringVar(root)
variable2.set(yogaposes.hamstringposes[0])

def change_image2(b):
    print(b)  # selected option
    my_image.config(image=yoga_dict2[b])
    
my_image = tk.Label(root)
my_image.grid(pady=20, row=1, column=1)

o = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable2, *yogaposes.hamstringposes, command=change_image2)
def optdrops():
    opt2 = o
    opt2.config(width=50, font=('Helvetica', 12))
    opt2.grid(pady=10, row=1, column=1, sticky='n')

def onclickHamstring(args):
    if args == 1:
        if (ci2_k['state'] == tk.NORMAL):
            ci2_k['state'] = tk.DISABLED
        else:
            ci2_k['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    if args == 2:
        if (ci2_k['state'] == tk.DISABLED):
            ci2_k['state'] = tk.NORMAL
            optdrops()
        else:
            ci2_k['state'] = tk.DISABLED
        o.destroy()
        my_image.destroy()

        
ci2_k = tk.Button(root, text="Hamstring poses", command=lambda:[onclickHamstring(1), optdrops()])
ci2_k.grid(pady=10, row=0, column=1)

normalizeyogabuttons = tk.Button(root, text="Refresh", command=lambda:onclickHamstring(2))
normalizeyogabuttons.grid(pady=10, row=2, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have defined your opt2 in `onclickHamstring` function and you are performing `destroy` in other function. Hence it wont work. You have to call that `opt2` optionmenu globally

Comment: @Karthik The reason I didn't want to put it in global is because I only want the optionmenu to appear when I click the "Hamstring" button. Is there a work around?

Comment: Though its not a good approach, but you can try using global variable for opt2. `global opt2`

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: There's nothing specific to tkinter here. No matter what type of object you're talking about, you need a reference to that object in order to call a method on that object.

Comment: `global` would fix this issue.

Comment: @Karthik Ok guys thanks for your input! I think I figured it out. I got stuck with another issues. I'm able to destroy the image and the optionmenu when I click "Refresh" button. But now, when I click hamstring button again, nothing happens. Possibly because I used destroy(). Any way to fix this? I updated my post with version 2